# JIRA How many values contains a field - JQL

Tags: jira, jql

Could you tell me how to use JQL to check how many Values contains a field (multiple values field)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible. Atlassian (company developing Jira) hasn't implemented it. There are more people requiring this feature though, the ticket "JQL count()-function for multi-value-fields" can be found here:

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-65152

I would suggest to vote for this issue, which might motivate Atlassian to implement the count() feature for multiple value fields. Currently there are 43 votes already. I just voted for it.